# How do I select an element by its style from css (not inline) using webdriver (python)

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors

I wish to use python-webdriver to select an element based on it's background highlighting colour. Normally, this bit of html:

```
<div class="line-highlight" style="background:#FD71B5;">
```

I would select it doing the following:

```
.line-highlight[style*='background:#FD71B5']
```

However, in this case I have different inline styling:

```
<div class="line-highlight" style=top:130px;height:28px;left:506px;width:434px;">
```

but the highlight colour (which is the same) is set in an external CSS, so the above selector does not seem to work.

Is there any way webdriver can select by style if that style is not inline?

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: Not directly with a CSS selector. You will need to select `.line-highlight` and ask for its computed style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the css you're looking for isn't part of the HTML markup you can't select element(s) as you would usually do.

Instead try to select by the class name ".line-highlight" then loop through the resulting element objects and for each element get the css background property value by using:

```
value_of_css_property("background")
```

(or any css property for that matter). Once an element matches the background you're looking for break from the loop and tada you found the element you are looking for.

*Note if you're using Java use:*

```
getCssValue(property-name)
```

Comment: Hmm, so I should be able to do something along the lines of this to find the colour and work from there: 
`element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".line-highlight")
element.value_of_css_property('color')`
Okay great - thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `element.value_of_css_property('background')`

Answer (score 0):

What this link http://www.w3.org/2002/07/26-dom-article.html says about style.

*Accessing the Style Associated With the Document


Each node in the document is associated with stylistic effects such as color, position, and
borders. These stylistic effects are not always part of the document and might be defined in
a separate section called a style sheet.*

So as Selenium works with DOM only it can't locate elements as you want.